# How to clone an iOS device (iPad), including app data container?

Tags: ios, ipad, configuration, apple-configurator

I have an iOS app on the app Store.

This app **can download additional content for free**. This content is stored in the user "application support" directory ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897825/ios-temporary-folder-location)). Once downloaded the app provides more content, just like Kindle would after downloading a few free e-books.

Now, **how can I clone this iPad, including its"updated" app, on 60 others ?** Apple Configurator does not seem to be able to clone the application AND its support directory. Am I missing a specific setting ?

Comment: What is the goal of this clone ? If it's for test purpose you could simply copy the directory of the simulator and embed it in your app.

Comment: It is a medical app. The "base" app has 5 cases. The "enhanced" app (after downloads) has 15 cases. I need to use this app on an audience of 60 physicians, and I can not afford the risk of a bandwidth breakdown when 60 people will try to download the 10 additional cases. So the idea is to build a "master" ipad filled with the app+additional cases, and clone it on 59 other devices.

TestFlight is unsuitable for this, because I haven't the emails of everybody (and that would exceed 100). My only solution is to download the cases on each iPad : imagine that...

Comment: Apple Configurator does provide this exact functionality. Can you please describe what you tried in apple configurator to get this done. Does your app have 'Application supports iTunes file sharing' enabled in the info.plist?