# I created a UIImage as a snapshot of my video in Swift. How can I get a temporary path to it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

So I used this code:

```
func videoSnapshot(filePathLocal: String) -> UIImage? {

    let vidURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:filePathLocal as String)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: vidURL)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    let timestamp = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 60)

    do {
        let imageRef = try generator.copyCGImageAtTime(timestamp, actualTime: nil)
        return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

to get the `UIImage` of a snapshot from my video. I called this function like this:

```
let tempImg: UIImage = videoSnapshot(pathToFile)!
```

now I would like to upload this tempImg to my server, and to to this I need a path to this file - I will pass it later to the function that uploads data further. How can I get a temporary path to it and store it as a `String` or `NSURL`?

Comment: get the image data using JPEG Data Representation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726643/how-to-compress-of-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-before-uploading-to-parse-as-pffi/29726675#29726675 and use NSData method writeToURL or writeToPath to save it to disk. You can save it at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897825/ios-temporary-folder-location/39318537#39318537

Comment: Thanks Leo, I understand the first link, now I have the `UIImage` saved as a `NSData`, but I don't understand the 2nd link - how can I save this `NSData` to the temp directory? (I'm using Swift 2)

Comment: just use `yourData.writeToURL(destination: url, options: .atomic)`. You can create a new url for the destination using URL appendingPathComponent `tmpURL.appendingPathComponent("fileName.xxx")`

Comment: Thanks man, do you bother to submit it as an answer to this question so that I could accept it?

Comment: user3766930 You are welcome. You should update your Xcode to version 8. You can still use Swift legacy 2.3 on your projects if you don't want to use Swift 3

Comment: I will post it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the image data using JPEG Representation method (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726643/how-to-compress-of-reduce-the-size-of-an-image-before-uploading-to-parse-as-pffi/29726675#29726675) so UIImageJPEGRepresentation  answer) and use NSData method writeToURL or writeToPath to save it to disk. For temporary items you can create a destination url at the [temporary folder url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897825/ios-temporary-folder-location/39318537#39318537) using URL appendingPathComponent method:

Swift 3 would look like this:

```
let destinationURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("filename.jpg")
if let tempImg = videoSnapshot("filePathLocal"),
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImg, 1) {
    do {
        try  imgData.write(to: destinationURL, options: .atomic)
        print("saved at:", destinationURL.path)
    } catch   {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Swift 2.3

```
if let tempImg = videoSnapshot("filePathLocal"),
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImg, 1),
    let destinationURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().temporaryDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("filename.jpg")
    where imgData.writeToURL(destinationURL, atomically: true) {
    print("saved at:", destinationURL.path)
}
```