# How to save a video to a URL in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: swift, url, nsfilemanager, swift-playground, phlivephoto

I'm trying to instantiate a `PHLivePhoto` but whenever I try to save the video that constitutes the live photo I can't get it to work.

Here's a little code snippet I wrote that handles **exporting** the video:

```
public func exportFilteredVideo(to outputURL: URL, completion: @escaping (Void) -> Void) {
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputURL.path) {
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
    }

    let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)!
    export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    export.outputURL = outputURL
    export.videoComposition = generateComposition()
    export.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: completion)
}
```

This is when I try to **retrieve** the video:

```
let destURL = url.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("Test.mov")
pixellationFilter.exportFilteredVideo(to: destURL) {
     print(try! destURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) //An error is thrown! Why though, isn't the export completed?
}
```

Currently, my suspicions are you might not be able to write to the `URL` specified. However, my understanding is that whenever I want to create a `PHLivePhoto` object I need to specify the resources as `URL` instead of `Data`. If this is possible, I would be able to instead use the data instead of exporting it to a `URL`. I could be wrong, but I'm not really finding a way to create a `PHLivePhoto` with `Data`. There is a `PHAssetResource` class but that only helps to get the data files of the `PHLivePhoto` not to create a `PHLivePhoto`.

So my possible solutions I believe at this moment are:

1. Figure out how I can save the video as a `URL`.
2. Try and create a live photo through `Data` instead of `URL`.

Comment: the fileURL it is just where the data is located

Comment: @LeoDabus Agreed, but when creating a `PHLivePhoto` I need to use this method: `request(with​Resource​File​URLs:​placeholder​Image:​target​Size:​content​Mode:​result​Handler:​)`. As you can see it takes a `[URL]` as an argument instead of `Data`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Here's the relevant documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phlivephoto/1616434-request

Comment: Just write the data to a temporary folder and pass that file url

Comment: @LeoDabus Do you mean create a new temporary folder or use `FileManager` to fetch an existing temporary folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39318537/2303865

Comment: Understood :), I'll use FileManger then. I'll let you know shortly if it works.

Comment: @LeoDabus It worked! Thank you soooo much. I thought that the bundle url should work, but Temporary Directory worked. If you would like to you can answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fileURL it is just where the data is located. Just write the data to a [temporary folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39318537/2303865) and pass that file url to the method.