# How to display .doc files in QLPreviewController swift language

Tags: ios, swift, doc, qlpreviewcontroller

I am new to ios developement, i am trying to display file with different format (ex. docx,doc,pdf,csv) , it is working fine with .pdf files but for .doc files its not previewing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdeu3.png)

This is what showing in simulator

For **some** .doc files & pdf it works!!1

code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
@IBAction func handlePress(){

    let previewController = QLPreviewController()
    previewController.dataSource = self
    present(previewController, animated: true)
}
func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
    return 3
}
func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    guard let url = URL(string: "**urlpath**/q.DOC") else {
       fatalError("Could not load")
    }

    return url as QLPreviewItem
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and post your code. Have you tried with another word doc file?

Comment: URL(string: ) initializer usually it is used for remote url. If your document url it is not a fileURL you would need to download your remote resource first

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140314/how-to-display-remote-document-using-qlpreviewcontroller-in-swift/47141577?r=SearchResults&s=2|28.5943#47141577

Answer (score 2):

First you need to download file and save in local storage. And one more thing is `.do` file is not supposed. So you have to take sure that your file is `.docx` or `.pdf`.

You can try this way :

```
func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {

    // ---- First way -----
    guard let strPath =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo.docx", ofType: nil) else { return "" as! QLPreviewItem }
    //guard let strPath =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo", ofType: "docx") else { return "" as! QLPreviewItem }
    let filePath = "file://\(strPath)"
    let url = URL(string: filePath)

    // ---- Second way -----
    guard let strPath =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo.docx", ofType: nil) else { return "" as! QLPreviewItem }
    //guard let strPath =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "demo", ofType: "docx") else { return "" as! QLPreviewItem }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: strPath)

    return url as QLPreviewItem
}
```

[image: .docx file display on iPhone]